# Reference Request: Representing Positive Integers as Differences with Minimal Hamming Weight

Tags: reference-request, algorithms

Background of my reference request is an observation that I made, while I was still in  school: there are two ways to calculate $x*999$: either do it directly, by applying the multiplication algorithm that is taught in school or, calculate it as $x*1000-x*1$ of which the second way is much easier.
But, I had no clue about the rules behind such a simplification.

Later, having studied computer science and math, and having learned of binary digits, things got clearer and I realized that the objective would be to express the multiplicator as a difference of non-negative integers with a minimal number of 1-bits in the binary representation.
Despite the fact that such a representation could speed up multiplication via repeated addition plus one subtraction or, exponentiation via repeated squaring plus one division, I could not find any mentioning of that representation or how to obtain an optimal such representation.

**I would therefore appreciate any pointers to information about the construction and properties of the representation of natural numbers as a difference with minimal Hamming weight.**

My currently best algorithm to determine a such difference-representation with a small Hamming weight is to
first fill "fissions", i.e. replace 0-bits that are next to two 1-bits on the left and on the right, so $...11011...$ becomes $...11111...$
and then replace each bit of an uninterrupted sequences of at least three 1-bits by 0-bits and, each 0-bit that is immediately to the left of such a sequence, by 1-bit so that $...011...10...$ would become $...100...00...$
With that operations, 27 would first become 31 due to fixing the fission and finally 32; the difference-representation is then 32-5 with a Hamming weight of 3 instead of 4.

An interesting phenomen is, that there are bit-patterns like $0010011011$, for which the difference encoding reduces the Hamming weight also for the bit-complement and, there are others, like $0110011$, for which no improvement is possible, even for the bit-complement.
This raises the question about the statistical properties of the quotient of the Hamming weights of difference encoding and of standard encoding of numbers.

EDIT:
In order to give some impression of the amount of operations that can be saved, I applied the method to the first 200 binary digits of some wellknown constants; the percentages relate to the number of 1-bits:

$60\% \approx 67/111$ Khinchin constant
$66\% \approx 71/108$ Chapernowne constant
$66\% \approx 72/109$ ln(2)
$68\% \approx 75/111$ Conway constant
$68\% \approx 75/110$ sqrt(2)
$69\% \approx 69/100$ Euler-Mascheroni constant
$70\% \approx 65/093$ Apéry constant
$73\% \approx 74/101$ Plastic Number
$73\% \approx 77/105$ $e$
$73\% \approx 77/105$ Golden ratio
$79\% \approx 70/089$ Feigenbaum constant
$83\% \approx 68/082$ $\pi$

Below, the binary digits of the respective constants are listed; boldface runs of digits incur a saving of additions that equal to #*bits*-(2 + #*0-bits*):

Khinchin constant
10.1010 **111101111** 00 **111** 00100001000 **1111** 000 **11011** 01000011010 **11101111** 0010 **111111011111** 00 **11111** 000 **111** 0010100011001100 **11111111** 00 **111** 00001100 **111** 0010010 **111** 000000010000 **1111** 00110000110000010100 **11101110111111** 010010011

Chapernowne constant
0.000 **111111** 0011010 **110111** 0100 **1101111** 01010001000 **1111111** 01000000 **111** 000001101010011000 **111110111** 000010 **110111** 01000000 **111111111111** 01001010100000 **111** 0100101010 **11011011** 001101010 **11011011** 00000010100 **111011** 000100011001

ln(2)
0.101100010 **111** 001000010 **1111111011111** 01000 **111** 00 **111101111** 001101010 **1111** 00100 **1111** 000 **111011** 00 **111** 0011000000000 **111111** 0010 **1111011** 01010 **1111** 01000000 **1111** 001101000011001001100 **111** 00101001100010 **11011** 00010 **11011** 000101

Conway constant
1.0100 **110110110111** 00 **1111** 01011010100100 **11111011** 00010010000010101010 **11111** 00010101001010101010 **1111** 00 **111** 010101100010101100 **111011111** 00 **111110110110111** 000100 **1110111** 00000 **111** 0001001010 **111** 00 **111** 0100100101000 **1111**

sqrt(2)
1.011010100000100 **1111** 0011001100 **1111111** 00 **11101111** 00110010010000100010110010 **11111011** 000100 **11011** 00 **110111** 01010100101010 **11111** 0100 **11111** 000 **111** 010 **1101111011** 0000010 **111** 0101000100100 **1110111** 010100001001100 **111011** 01

Euler-Mascheroni constant
0.100100 **1111** 00010001100 **111111** 000 **11011111011011** 000011000 **1111** 01001001101000 **11011111** 000 **1111111** 0000001000000010101001011001011010101101010000 **111** 00 **111011** 00110000 **111** 010 **1111011** 0010 **111** 001100000000011001000011

Apéry constant
1.001100 **1110111** 010000000000100 **1111** 0000000001100010000100 **111** 00000 **110111** 00010 **111** 0001010 **111** 000101100 **1111** 00110100100000 **1111111** 000 **11011** 00011000000010 **11011111011011** 00010 **111** 01001001001101000000010 **1110111** 01001

Plastic number
1.010100110010000010 **110111** 0100 **111011** 001010010001001010 **11011** 010110000010 **1111** 000100010010 **11111** 00010000010100011000010011001101000 **111** 00 **11011111111** 00000010 **111** 0010 **1111** 000 **111** 00 **11111** 010 **111011** 01010110000110011

$e$
10.10 **110111111** 00001010100010110001010001010 **111011** 01001010100110101010 **1111110111** 00010101100010000000100 **111** 00 **1111** 0100 **1111** 00 **1111** 000 **111011** 00010 **111** 00 **111** 000101100000 **1111** 00 **111** 00010110100 **11011** 0100101011010101

Golden ratio
1.100 **1111** 000 **11011101111** 00 **110111** 0010 **1111111** 010010100 **11111** 000001010 **11111** 00 **111** 00 **111** 001100000001100000010 **111** 00 **1110110111** 00100000110100000100001000001000100 **111011010111111** 00 **111** 01000100 **111** 00100101000 **111111**

Feigenbaum constant
100.1010101101010000110010 **111111** 000110000 **111** 0010010 **111** 01000 **111** 01000 **111** 0000000100 **111011** 01010001011010 **111** 000100110010000 **111111011** 010000000100010000110000000 **1111** 0001011000000010011000100 **111** 00101010101001

$\pi$
11.0010010000 **111111011** 0101010001000100001011010001100001000110100110001001100011001100010100010 **111** 0000000 **110111** 00000 **111** 001101000100101001000000100100 **111** 0000010001000101001100 **11111** 0011000 **111** 01000000001

Comment: Somewhere up there, without telling anyone, you shifted from decimal to binary. Maybe you could rewrite the question so that it's clearer what base you're working in, and when.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: following your suggestion, I edited the problem description to make the transition from decimal to binary encoding more explicit. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtraction will produce an improvement in total weight if and only if there is an interval of $k$ bits where then number $r$ of ones satisfies $2r > k+2$.

*Proof:* We may assume the interval is preceded by a zero.  Subtraction will transform it into the difference between the length $k+1$ string $10\cdots0$ (with 1 one) and the twos-complement (with $k-r+1$ ones).  Total ones before: $r$.  Total ones after: $k-r+2$.

We can call intervals satisfying the previous bound "good".  If you have a good interval, your total weight doesn't change if you subdivide it at a place where there are two consecutive zeroes, and the total weight decreases if there are more than two consecutive zeroes.  This means that a straightforward greedy algorithm will produce a minimal representation: start from one end or the other, and start forming a candidate interval when you hit a one.  If you hit two zeroes, end your candidate interval, and check whether the number of ones satisfies the bound for goodness.

I think the reason this method is not used in multiplication algorithms is that it only yields a substantial advantage for a very small proportion of possible numbers.  When $n$ is large, almost all $n$-bit numbers have very close to $n/2$ ones in the binary representation, and the bits are generally not clustered enough to make it advantageous to replace a single multiplication operation with a cluster search plus two multiplications plus a subtraction.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the conditions under which the suggested difference-representation is beneficial.  I see practical applicability of the difference-representation in the repeated multiplication with compile-time constants if additions/subtractions are very expensive like e.g. in the scaling of long vectors of data; could be an idea for optimization in generated code.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That sounds neat.

Answer (score 0):

More extended comment than answer:

My understanding is that this is basically the idea behind the Fast Fourier transform multiplication algorithm. My impression is that the intuition behind finding Fourier coefficients is the same as your intuition, *i.e.*, expressing numbers in terms of "basis" elements (like $1000$ in your initial example), and doing so as efficiently as possible, so that operations on these bases are easy.

So, for instance, we can view an $n$-bit number as a point in $\{0,1\}^n$ written in terms of the basis points $(1,0,0,\dots), (0,1,0,0,\dots),\dots$. Then we can use the Fourier transform to write it in terms of some other, more convenient basis, do some operations in that space, then convert it back to get the results of our multiplication.

But usually this is done in $\mathbb{C}$ and the bases are the $n$th roots of unity. I wish I knew more about this whole process, specifically, why the $n$th roots of unity are chosen as a basis and whether some other basis would work as well; also, I would be interested to know how a general Fourier transform would work for your particular setting (Hamming distance), but unfortunately I don't have the understanding to say. I hope someone else can perhaps respond and explain!

Anyway, there's some explanation of the FFT algorithm on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods) page, and an explanation of the FFT algorithm for multiplying polynomials is in Chapter 2, section 2.6 of *Algorithms* by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani, [available for free](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap2.pdf).

---

Comment: I know about the role of FFT in efficient multiplication, but expressing numbers by differences is much easier to understand and to implement. That doesn't however mean that I think that the difference encoding is better - it depends on what you need.

Comment: @ManfredWeis, maybe I didn't express it well, but I'm just trying to say that it sounds like you are doing the same thing as the FFT algorithm, except with a different choice of basis. If that's true (or even if not), you could look at the general Fourier transform approach to see if it could give the construction you're looking for.

Comment: I think the essence of FFT multiplication is that it replaces the $O(n^2)$ convolution in ordinary multiplication with an $O(n)$ pointwise product.  That doesn't seem to be taking place here.

Comment: @usul: I understood your pointer to FFT correctly; it will certainly give new insights to elaborate the differences and similarities to the FFT technique. I used the difference representation in software for embedded systems to emulate the multiplication of integer variables with compile-time real values without the use of multiplication (replaced by shifts and adds) or real values (replaced by repeated adding an integer, followed by a shift); in that special case FFT would have been an overkill in my opinion.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: concerning your statement that "generally the bits are not clustered enough", I did some further searching of the internet and stumbled across "coin-tossing" and statistics about the distribution of longest runs or distributions of run length (which exceed my level of statistics) from which I got the impression that clusters are not that rare that their appearance would come as a surprise. From that I conclude that the topic of minimal Hamming weight in the difference representation of positive integers would be worth deeper statistical analyses.